# Tag wiki excerpt history applies Markdown formatting to what should be plain text

Tags: bug, revisions-list, tag-wiki-excerpt

For example, on the [array-shift](/questions/tagged/array-shift)  [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12527224/revisions), note that the edits are rendered with Markdown previews.

> [image: tag excerpt history showing code formatting]

(E.g. the code-ified and linked array_unique() at the start of my post.)

Markdown is not supported in excerpts, so this should not happen.

This is still an issue eight years later.

Comment: IMO the `side-by-side markdown` option should not be available and the `inline` and `side-by-side` options should both operate on plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious, so I decided to do some digging regarding tag excerpts using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (specifically in excerpts, since Markdown isn't a problem in wiki bodies).

On Stack Overflow, there are (at time of writing) 40,573 tags with non-empty excerpts<sup>1</sup>.

I wanted to discover how many of these excerpts contained Markdown syntax (which isn't being rendered), so I pulled them into a CSV from the data explorer and constructed some regular expressions to help find them.

Here are my findings:

- Tag links `[tag:_TAGNAME_]`

  - ~167 tags contain one or more
- Newlines<sup>2</sup>

  - 2,465 tags include at least 1 newline character in their excerpt

    - At least 1,326 of these are mid-body line breaks, rather than ending ones
- Text formatted as `code`

  - Between 603 and 676 tags
- Markdown style links `[name](website)`

  - 5 tags<sup>3</sup>
- Italicized or emboldened text

  - Between 53 and 81 tags

Combining all the expressions I used to pull these numbers<sup>4</sup>, I got roughly **838** unique tag excerpts containing markdown syntax.

This was actually *way* less than I expected, to be honest. It accounts for a very small number of tags percentage wise, only **2.07%** of all tags with non-empty excerpts. Still, that's not nothing.

I would assume this hasn't been fixed yet due to it not being trivial to swap out the editor for tag wiki excerpts. In my understanding, that would help solve most of the problem, since not seeing rendered markdown in the editor would definitely discourage its use.

Even 8 years on, this should definitely still get addressed.

---

<sup>1</sup> - [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1307841/get-all-non-empty-tag-excerpts)
<sup>2</sup> - In practice, line breaks are often not very problematic, but they are not rendered in excerpts.
<sup>3</sup> - If someone is inclined to fix them, they're [corvid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/corvid/info), [gqlgen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gqlgen/info), [quire-api](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/quire-api/info), [usart](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/usart/info), and [yang](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yang/info).
<sup>4</sup> - [Here's a link](https://regex101.com/r/R2Zedx/1) to the monstrosity of a RegExp that I used.

Comment: I've been trying to correct some of these issues (i.e. removing the formatting from the excerpt) but it takes a while...