# Tag wiki excerpt for R repeatedly edited to add hyperlink

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, tag-wiki-excerpt

Following several discussion on meta regarding hyperlinks in tag wiki excerpts, I've suggested an edit to remove the hyperlink in [r](/questions/tagged/r) excerpt.

Unfortunately, the hyperlink returned, in an unanimously approved suggestion:

[image]

So the question is, should this edit be undone? Should I suggest another edit equal to my previous one?

obs: Relevant link: [exerpt history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3625322/revisions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably because the [hyperlinks get rendered when reviewing the suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147829/tag-excerpt-history-applies-markdown-formatting-to-posts) (it's even rendered in the revision history, as you can see), but don't actually get rendered in the popup box. People are less likely to notice or think about the problem when reviewing.

I've undone the edit. It's obviously incorrect since it looks horrid in that popup.

Comment: It would be really nice if tag wiki excerpts didn't allow hyperlinks, but I guess that would probably fall under "Meh" priority